# VBA copy after Criteria in other file

Tags: excel, vba

I must copy after 3 column , for 3 Region - which have an X on rows if my info are for NAFTA,Europe and Asia.The info should be copy from MasterDate -MacroMaster file to Prices_Database_ For_ Volume_Europe.I create below code for Europe but don't work and don't generate any error.Please advise.

```
Sub Copy_Data_From_Macro_FileinDB() ' copy data from Macro file to DB file 
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To lCopyLastRow

    If Cells(i, 11) = "EU" And Cells(i, lCopyLastRow) = “x” Then
     Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MacroMaster file.xlsm").Sheets("MasterData")
     Set wsDest = Workbooks("Prices_Database_ For_ 
     Volume_Europe.xlsx").Sheets("MasterData")

     lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

     wsCopy.Range("A2:AB" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
     wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

     Workbooks("Prices_Database_ For_ Volume_Europe.xlsx").Close 
     SaveChanges:=True
     Workbooks("MacroMaster 
     file.xlsm").Worksheets("MasterData").Range("A2:AB100").ClearContents
     End If

     Next i
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your for-loop is not working, because you are using `lCopyLastRow` there before you define it. You should place this bit:

```
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MacroMaster file.xlsm").Sheets("MasterData")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Prices_Database_ For_ 
    Volume_Europe.xlsx").Sheets("MasterData")

   lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

Outside of the for-loop.

Also when working with different worksheets/workbooks, I would suggest using `wsCopy.Cells(i, 11)` etc in your if-statement if that's the sheet you are looking in, because if your other workbook is somehow activated, it might look at the wrong workbook.

Also i'm not really seeing what the for-loop does, because each time you find a row where Column K is "EU" and another cell is "x" (which is strange, because you are using the last row variable as a column number), you copy the entire range to the bottom of the destination sheet. It seems more logical that you only need to copy 1 row at a time here. In that case you should use

`wsCopy.Range("A" & i & ":AB" & i).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)`

Finally, when you are handling a large amount of rows, I would suggest to not use Copy/Paste at all, since it's quite slow. You can also say:

`wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow & ":AB" & lDestLastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("A" & i & ":AB" & i).Value`

Comment: Hello Alex de Jong - so wsCopy.Range("A" & i & ":AB" & i).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow) is work but only from 1 row which is copy from Master file (the last).

Comment: I need all rows from Master macro file to be copy in destination file for each row from column K which =x value.The same when I copy information from Macro file I don't need column L,M but I need column from N to AB.Please can advise?Thank you